# When Can I say odds ratio is important to analyze my data

Tags: odds-ratio, odds

Lets say in my data if I generate odds ratio between 2 variable A and B and get that the odds ratio is 2-5 is that a good thing to dive deep further or should I move to other relations .

Comment: Only you can determine that.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the field you are working in, the precision of your estimates, the costs of a mistake and so on.

There are cases where a quite small OR might be very important (e.g. if you can reduce the likelihood of an airplane crashing by 1%, that would be interesting) and other cases where  a much larger OR might not be interesting. E.g. if you decreased the risk of a defective light bulb by 20% but the new light bulb cost 5 times as much - not so interesting.